# Too many queries per page

Tags: php, mysql, performance, yii2

I'm using Yii2 and Yii2's standard way to fetch data from database. Using also JOINs, it takes 23 queries to fetch 90 rows + some other stuff loaded with the page.

But when I start showing data in table, it becomes critical. Every row has multiple pictures and I take only one picture to show. That's when number of queries go above 100.

This is how I fetch that one image:

```
Table1::find()->where(['IDauction'=>$ID])->limit(1)->orderBy('ID ASC')->one();
```

Very simple query, but when I have 90 rows and each row execute this query it goes above 100 per page. I'm not sure how to fix this, because when I show all data using relations number of queries go above 500. For example I fetch user's profile image also and that image is in different table.

This is how I do it currently

```
$query = Auction::find();
$query->joinWith(['relationIDpigeon', 'relationIDuser']);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['start_time'=>SORT_DESC]],//newest first
    'pagination'=>
    [
        'pageSize'=>100,
    ]
]);
```

Comment: You should look into Eager loading.  Its fairly common with ORM frameworks to need to do this.  Here is the documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/527/relational-query-lazy-loading-and-eager-loading-with-and-together/  Just go to the Eager loading section to see how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't written correctly.  Also you should set up your relations in Yii.  That way you can reference related tables and row.

Your query should look like this

```
$result = Table1::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('IDauction' =>$ID),array('order'=>'ID ASC','limit'=> 1));
```

And referencing related fields like this

```
$related_rows = $result->related_rows;
```

Comment: I'm using yii2 and relations like you showed, but still have to fetch that one image that, I think, cannot be fetched via relations since there are many picture for one row

Comment: The question is about Yii2, not Yii1.